# INSERT column rows from backup table to new one

Tags: mysql, python-3.5

I'm updating my database structure and did a few tets.

My table exists out of many columns but the main columns i want to talk about is 'last_connection' 'time_on_the_server' 'connections' and 'contested'. I have 2 tables one is the new one I want to use 'NewTable' and 'NewTable_backup'.

The Database structure is almost the same, but I want to use the columns from NewTable_backup in the NewTable. (They are 0, 0, 0, 0 on NewTable but have values on NewTable_backup.)

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT` is for adding new rows. To modify existing rows, you use `UPDATE`. Use an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` to get the values from the corresponding row in the other table.

```
UPDATE NewTable AS t
JOIN NewTableBackup AS b ON t.id = b.id
SET t.last_connection = b.last_connection,
    t.time_on_the_server = b.time_on_the_server,
    t.connections = b.connections,
    t.contested = b.contested
```